# IllegalArgumentException when calling invoke method using Java Reflections

Tags: java, reflection, invoke

I have a class that has a method as follows :-

```
public void setCurrencyCode(List<String> newCurrencycode){
    this.currencycode = newCurrencycode;
}
```

I am using Java Relections to invoke this method as follows :-

```
try {
    List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
    value.add("GB");

    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName( "com.xxx.Currency" );
    Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
    Class param[] = { List.class };
    Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod( "setCurrencyCode", param );
    method.invoke( value );
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println( "Exception : " + e.getMessage() );
}
```

However, an exception is raised on the "invoke" call :-
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Any ideas?

Thanks

Sarah

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that the `value` object you pass into `invoke` is not an instance of the class on which the `method` is defined.  This is because the first argument of invoke is the object on which to *make* the call, and the subsequent arguments are the parameters to the invoked method.  (In this case it looks like value needs to be an instance of `com.xxx.Currency` - which of course it isn't, because it's a `List`.)

Since you're calling a non-static method (and going to to trouble of creating a new instance), then for the reflective equivalent of `obj.setCurrencyCode(value)`, at the end of your try block you'd need to call

```
method.invoke(obj, value)
```

instead of your current single one-arg call.

Comment: Fantastic!  I hadn't noticed that there were more than 1 invoke method!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

You are not calling [invoke()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) correctly: `invoke()` expects the target object as the first parameter, then the parameters to the method call as the following parameters (since java 1.5, it's a varargs parameter)

Try this:

```
try 
    {
        List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
        value.add("GB");

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName( "com.xxx.Currency" );
        Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
        // Since java 1.5, you don't need Class[] for params: it's a varargs now 
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod( "setCurrencyCode", List.class ); // you already have a reference to the class - no need for obj.getClass()
        method.invoke( obj, value ); // invoke expects the target object, then the parameters
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println( "Exception : " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```